# How should we validate regex syntax

Tags: java, regex, sonarqube

Our user is allowed to provide our app with some regex that we should do some matching on. As such we would like to validate the input when the user enters it.

We can do this using the following code:

```
    try {
        new String().matches(regEx);
    } catch (PatternSyntaxException e) {
        errors.addError(TASK_DETAILS.value(), "Invalid regular expression. " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

However, SonarQube that we are using to check code coverage, flags the call to matches up as a bug, claiming that: 'Return values from functions without side effects should not be ignored'. I can get rid of the bug by placing the call to matches inside a method called 'parse' or 'format' but I'm really validating, so I want my method to start 'validate'.

Is there a better way of checking that the syntax is valid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call [`Pattern.compile`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#compile(java.lang.String)). But this returns a `Pattern` which SQ probably wants you to not ignore.

Wrap your code into a method that returns a `boolean`.

```java
private boolean regexIsValid(String regex) {
  try {
    return Pattern.compile(regex) != null;
  } catch (PatternSyntaxException e) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Then call this method.

```java
if (regexIsValid(regex)) {
  errors.addError(TASK_DETAILS.value(), "Invalid regular expression. ");
}
```

If you need the details of the `PatternSyntaxException`, return an `Optional<String>` from `regexIsValid` and check it.

```java
private Optional<String> regexIsValid(String regex) {
  try {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    return Optional.empty();
  } catch (PatternSyntaxException e) {
    return Optional.of(e.getMessge());
  }
}
```

```java
Optional<String> regexErrorMessage = regexIsValid(regex);
if (regexErrorMessage.isPresent()) {
  errors.addError(TASK_DETAILS.value(), "Invalid regular expression. " + regexErrorMessage.get());
}
```

Comment: your 2nd solution which returns Optional may lead to another SonarQube warning of unused variable "pattern"